# What is the time complexity of the below mentioned linked list algorithm

Tags: swift, algorithm, linked-list, time-complexity

I am writing an algorithm to remove the last N nodes from a linked list and append it to the front of the linked list as provided below

```
func removeAndAppendLastToFront(N: Int) {
    var slow: Node? = head
    var fast: Node? = head

    for _ in 0 ..< N - 1 {
        fast = fast?.next
    }

    var previous: Node?
    while fast?.next != nil {
        previous = slow
        slow = slow?.next
        fast = fast?.next
    }

    if previous != nil {
        previous?.next = nil
        fast?.next = head
        head = slow
    }
}
```

However I am having some difficulty calculating the time complexity of this algorithm.

As per my understanding the first for loop should be a constant O(1)

```
 for _ in 0 ..< N - 1 {
        fast = fast?.next
 }
```

But, what about the second while loop, will it be O(log N) considering the fast pointer has been forwarded in linear time within the first for loop and the second while loop just continues from the last value stored?

```
  while fast?.next != nil {
        previous = slow
        slow = slow?.next
        fast = fast?.next
  }
```

And what will be the total time complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: THe complexity of first node should be O(n). Is not it? It will run N times .

Comment: check my answer to heikh hamza

Comment: @mahbubcseju I believe you are right, the N in this case is not exactly a constant value as it might be the head node itself, otherwise if the Nth value have been a constant it would have been O(1). So I guess the first loop will be O(N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how is your first loop O(1) when it goes from start to nth element? and as n is your final element you are practically recursing through the entire list
your first loop actually has O(N) and since you are at final element shouldnt it have no next element and should it not make fast?.next != nil condition false?

Comment: It's not exactly the Nth element, it's a constant provided by the user, basically the Nth node from the tail end of the linked list. I guess in the worst case analysis the Nth element could be the head node however in average it might not always be O(N). As for the logic involved I am using two pointer, slow and fast, and increment the fast pointer by the amount of nodes N from the end while looping from the head. After that I basically loop both until reaching the end of the linked list by which time I then know that the slow pointer will be at the node which needs to be moved to the front.

Comment: Considering both average and worst case scenarios I believe total will be O(N) only with both loops combined. What do you think?

Comment: yup exactly, in the worst case the algorithm has O(N) and in the best it would have O(1) complexity